# How to change dropdown button text to it's selected item name

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't been able to find an answer to this that is clear enough for me, so here I am:
I have a button and made it as a dropdown menu:

```
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="changeDropdownVisibility()" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="i-speed-drp" class="dropdown-content">
        <a id="i-speed-drp-m-s" value="m/s" onclick="changeButtonName('i-speed-drp-m-s', 'm/s')">meters per second (m/s)</a>
        <a id="i-speed-drp-km-h" value="km/h" onclick="changeButtonName('i-speed-drp-km-h', 'km/h')">kilometers per hour (km/h)</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    function changeButtonName(btnId, btnValue) {
        var btn = document.getElementById("i-greitis-dropdown");
    }
</script>
```

(I don't think css code is needed here, if so, please, write so)

What do I put in the `changeButtonName()` function to change the text of the button without it changing the texts of it's elements?

Comment: which button is this? `document.getElementById("i-greitis-dropdown");` there is no elements with that id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the `<a>` tags into `<button>` elements since you're not using it for navigation and the `value` property doesn't exist on the `<a>` tag.

Select both buttons and add an event listener to each button where you listen for `click` events. I'd recommend getting familiar with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). *Inline event handlers* are an old piece of tech and have some cons. [Read more about events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Set the `textContent` value of the dropdown button to the `value` of the clicked button.

```js
const dropDownButton = document.querySelector('#i-greitis-dropdown');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-button');

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    dropDownButton.textContent = event.target.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="i-greitis-dropdown" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</button>
  
  <div id="i-speed-drp" class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="dropdown-button" value="m/s">meters per second (m/s)</button>
    <button class="dropdown-button" value="km/h">kilometers per hour (km/h)</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript. Note it is enough to pass the element that was clicked and from that get:

- elem value
- elem closest parent dropdown
- dropdown btn

```js
function changeButtonName(elem) {
  var dropdown = elem.closest(".dropdown");
  var btn = dropdown.querySelector(".dropdown-btn");
  var btnValue = elem.getAttribute("value")
  btn.innerText = btnValue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="changeDropdownVisibility()" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="i-speed-drp" class="dropdown-content">
      <a id="i-speed-drp-m-s" value="m/s" onclick="changeButtonName(this)">meters per second (m/s)</a>
      <a id="i-speed-drp-km-h" value="km/h" onclick="changeButtonName(this)">kilometers per hour (km/h)</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("i-greitis-dropdown")
})
```

I think this should help